# Bootstrap: how to always take up 6 columns without defining each screen size

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to always take up X amount of columns without having to give it a class for each size: ex: `col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `col-6` (with no breakpoint) will apply it to all screen sizes.